In Quorum-Based Consensus Protocol, how does abort quorum get the updated data?
I am trying to understand "Quorum-Based Consensus Protocol". If there are total 5 nodes and 'Commit quorum' is of 3 nodes And 'Abort quorum' is also of 3 nodes. Now coordinator asks to prepare for commit. And it receives 3 yes and 2 no. Then co-ordinator tells 3 nodes to commit. Now 3 nodes have updated data. And 2 nodes have stale data. How does this inconsistency resolve? How will 2 nodes have the updated data? What if in future, all 5 nodes agree on 'prepare commit'?
